# Movie about a father and his daughter traveling in a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification

This movie should be at least ten years old. I remember a father and daughter travel on a ship to all sorts of lands like in a fairy tale. They meet all sorts of fascinating creatures like orcs. I remember title being about three words. This was very similar to the 10th Kingdom.

Comment: So it wasn't "the 10th Kingdom" then?

Comment: No, it wasn't. They were very similar, actually. Even one of the protagonists   looks like one from the other. I looked up IMDB on the filmographies of said character and found nothing. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Can you offer any more info about the characters, their ages, ethnicity, anything you remember about their appearances, the setting, whether they were native to the fairy world, etc

Comment: [Voyage of the Unicorn](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0249326/)

Comment: If it had vast amounts of inappropriate nudity, it might have been "[Prospero's books](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=prospero%27s+books)"

Comment: It wasn't. I watched this as a kid on my local TV channel with Sinhala subtitles.  But the movie was of foreign origin. Seemed pretty American.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I did not see your previous comments. That is the one! It's Voyage of the Unicorn! I appreciate your time ! Thank you very much! Now to watch it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing the 2001 made-for-TV movie "[Voyage of the Unicorn](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0249326/)"

> A professor, grieving for his dead wife, and his two daughters
>   unwillingly journey to a parallel universe of fairy court, marauding
>   trolls, and a prophecy that they will save this nether world. They
>   board the Unicorn, a magic ship manned by elves. In the search for a
>   dragon who will help them fulfill the prophecy, they encounter the
>   Minotaur, Medusa, the Sphinx, an ogre, and a unicorn whose tears they
>   need to reverse one of Medusa's misguided stares. The trolls also seek
>   the dragon. Capture and slavery awaits failure, while faith precedes
>   the miracle. The spirit of their mother is close to the girls, who
>   must find courage and imagination, while Dad must keep his wits.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!